# Meteor Dynamic Template not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

The line {{> Template.dynamic template=content }} makes my page not load. It actually crashes my browser sometimes. I had it working for a while but something happened and now it does not work anymore.
{{> Template.dynamic template='navBar' }} works so my packages should be ok.

Meteor: 1.4
Packages: kadira:flow-router, kadira:blaze-layout

imports/ui/layouts/mainLayout.html:

```
<template name="mainLayout">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      {{> navBar }}
    </div>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {{> Template.dynamic template=content }} <!-- not working -->
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>
```

imports/ui/layouts/mainLayout.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './mainLayout.html';
import '../components/navBar.html';
import '../pages/settings.html';
```

imports/startup/client/routes.js:

```
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { BlazeLayout } from 'meteor/kadira:blaze-layout';
import '../../ui/layouts/mainLayout.js';
import '../../ui/pages/settings.js';

FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'mainLayout' });
  },
});

FlowRouter.route('/settings', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'settings' });
  },
});
```

imports/ui/pages/settings.html:

```
<template name="settings">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is the settings page</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: So you are putting a layout within a layout?  `BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'mainLayout' });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'mainLayout' });
  },
});
```

is not going to work because you are inserting the `mainLayout` component into itself - the nested `content` helper is the issue. Instead, you should be rendering a different component into `content`:

```
BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'home' }); // or whatever component should be at "/"
```

Comment: I did some renaming of my files and my brain stopped working in the process. Thank you. It works.