# Meteor Template not working for root path

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to refer to my earlier question: [Meteor Dynamic Template not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582454/meteor-dynamic-template-not-working)

Using components in my app is working just fine on all other pages except on the root path:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'home' });
  },
});
```

The same components are working just fine here.

```
FlowRouter.route('/dashboard', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', { content: 'dashboard' });
  },
});
```

I have imported the same components in both home.js and dashboard.js. The location of the files are the same and the imports are identical. My components work on all pages, but not if is root path.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually solved by a complete reboot. I tried restarting the application multiple times without luck.